# Rails Deployment using Capistrano error: Could not extract RVM sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

Rails : 5
Capistrano Gem: capistrano (3.11.0) , rvm1-capistrano3 (1.4.0)
rvm: rvm 1.29.7

config/deploy/staging.rb ->

```
server 'xxxx', user: 'main_user', password: 'xxx', roles: [:app,:web]
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/staging.myserver.com'
set :branch, 'my_branch'
```

I am trying to deploy my Ruby/Rails code using Capistrano but I get following error->

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy 

DEBUG  Command: /usr/bin/env /var/www/staging.myserver.com/rvm1scripts/install-rvm.sh
 DEBUG      Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.7.tar.gz
 DEBUG      Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.7/1.29.7.tar.gz.asc
 DEBUG      gpg: Signature made xxxx using RSA key ID xxxxx
gpg: Good signature from xxx
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: xxxx
 DEBUG      GPG verified '/usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.7.tgz'
 DEBUG      gtar: .github: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted     
gtar: config: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
Could not extract RVM sources.
```

Is it just 'main_user' privilege issue? I am assured that the user has all the needed rights. How can I resolve this?

Update**->
1: A lot of forums online suggested downgrading RVM and I tried that too. Downgraded from RVM 1.29.7 to 1.29.3 but still the same problem

2: ls -l /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root rvm 1534 Feb  4 14:34 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm

cat /etc/group |grep -i rvm
rvm:x:1017:main_user

Comment: does utime command on remote side? ssh and test

Comment: probably you need to install it

Comment: @NeverBe what do you mean? utime
bash: utime: command not found...
Similar command is: 'time'

Comment: what is linux type you use?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise

Comment: take a look this https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4020

Comment: @NeverBe i have seen that thread. A lot of users suggested downgrading RVM and I tried that too. Downgraded from RVM 1.29.7 to 1.29.3 but still the same problem

Comment: looks like rvm installed under root, but deploying goes under another user

Comment: You might be right! How can I confirm & correct this?

Comment: reinstall rvm under user you deploy with

Comment: How can i confirm that rvm is currently installed under root?

Comment: rvm info and check folders permissions

Comment: I updated my question. The deployment user seems to be a part of the group 'rvm' that is allowed to run rvm

Comment: has main_user needed permissions?

Comment: as 'main_user', I can run rvm -v, rvm list, rvm use etc without using sudo or anything else